# Multiparameter GUI with button-driven update

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I would like to be able to evaluate a function based on multiple `Slider` values by pushing a `Button` that creates the function, produces the data, and also produces a plot in the same "GUI" window. This is like a `Manipulate` for a plot in many ways, but I want the update to be button-driven and not slider-driven (since the function evaluation is expensive). I expected to easily find an example, but my search-engine-foo failed me. To make this concrete, consider a distilled case: 2 sliders to set a slope and intercept of a univariate affine function, and then 1 button that produces the resulting function, evaluates it on a given list of inputs, and then produces a list plot (ideally in the "GUI" pane, or whatever). For this simplified example, the two parts to be integrated are something like

```
Column[{
  Grid[{
    {"b:", Manipulator[Dynamic[b0], ContinuousAction -> False]},
    {"m:", Manipulator[Dynamic[m0], ContinuousAction -> False]}
    }],
  Button["Run", With[{b = b0, m = m0},
    Print@With[{pts = Map[x |-> m*x + b, Range[10]]},
      ListPlot[pts]
      ]]]
  }]
```

However, ideally the variables will be local to the GUI, and the figure will be within the GUI frame and will *update* when the button is pressed (e.g., by updating the contents of a `Panel`). I definitely would not mind using a `FormObject` to achieve this.

Comment: You can use `TrackedSymbols` to limit the automatic updating to only some symbols. If you add a dummy symbol (e.g. with manipulate spec `{{dummy,0}, None}`), you can track updates to that symbol & change it when clicking the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relatively straightforward way to achieve what you seem to be after:

```
DynamicModule[{b = 0, m = 1, result = ""},
  Column[{
   Grid[{
     {"b:",Manipulator[Dynamic[b]]}, 
     {"m:",Manipulator[Dynamic[m]]}
   }],
   Button["Run",
     result = "calculating...";
     Pause[1];
     result = ListPlot[Map[x |-> m*x + b, Range[10]]],
     Method -> "Queued"
   ],
   Dynamic[result]
 }]
]
```

Note that I added an artificial `Pause` to simulate the "expensive" calculation and added a simple progress info as you mentioned that the calculation itself is expensive and the button only makes sense in that case. I also added `Method->"Queued"` which will avoid that you run into timeouts when exceeding the corresponding limits which I think is also important when your calculation really is expensive...

Here is a slightly more elaborated version which:

- allows to abort
- extract the lengthy calculation in an extra function
- takes full control of all gui-updates

I think this probably can serve as a starting point for many similar use cases:

```
DynamicModule[{b = 0, m = 1, result = "", running = False},
  Column[
    {
      Grid[{
        {"b:", Manipulator[Dynamic[b]]}, 
        {"m:", Manipulator[Dynamic[m]]}
      }]
      ,
      Dynamic[
        If[Not @ running,
          Button["Run", 
            result = ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate"]; 
            running = True; 
            WithCleanup[
              result = CheckAbort[runCalculation[m,b],"aborted!"]
              , 
              running = False
            ],
            Method -> "Queued"
          ],
          Button["Abort", FrontEndToken["EvaluatorAbort"], Evaluator->None]
        ],
        TrackedSymbols :> {running}
      ],
      Dynamic[result, TrackedSymbols :> {result}]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: This seems quite satisfactory. I upvoted but I'm going to play with it a bit before accepting. Thanks!

Comment: For the first approach, "calculating" won't appear; right? Also, I initialized result with a blank graphic (just axes) for a bit better initial look. Still happy!

Comment: Good to heat this helped. The problem with "calculating" not appearing I also noticed, but for me it was only happening for the first click on the run button, and I think it completely was gone in the second version with  the explicit TrackedSymbol option for the last Dynamic. Is it persisting for you?

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`TrackedSymbols`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) so that [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) only updates when `Run` is toggled.

```
Manipulate[
 If[run, m = mv; b = bv; run = False];
 pts = Table[{x, m*x + b}, {x, 0, 10}];
 ListPlot[pts,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]})],
 {{mv, 1, "slope"}, 0.1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{bv, 0, "intercept"}, -10, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{run, False, Style["Run", 14, Blue]}, {True, False}, 
  ControlType -> Checkbox},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols -> run]
```

[image]